# Combine vector and single row of data frame into a list

Tags: r

I am trying to assemble a list out of a vector and a row of a data
frame. The list will be passed to `do.call()` as the arguments to a
function. If the vector is length 1, no problem.

```r
tbl <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:4,
              b = letters[1:4])

vec <- 1
works <- c(avec = vec, as.list(tbl[1,]))
testit <- function(avec, a, b){
  length(avec) + length(a) + length(b)
}
do.call(testit, works)
#> [1] 3
```

But it also needs to work with longer vectors

```r
vec <- 1:2 
broken <- c(avec = vec, as.list(tbl[2,]))# breaks apart avec
do.call(testit, broken)
#> Error in (function (avec, a, b) : unused arguments (avec1 = 1, avec2 = 2)

toomany <- list(avec = vec, as.list(tbl[2,]))#too many layers
do.call(testit, toomany)
#> Error in (function (avec, a, b) : argument "b" is missing, with no default


#what I want:
whatIwant <- list(avec = 1:2, a = 2, b = "b")
do.call(testit, whatIwant)
#> [1] 4
```

It doesn’t matter if a data frame, and I want solution to work with both
tibbles and dataframes anyhow.

```r
adf <- data.frame(a = 1:4,
                  b = letters[1:4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
list(avec = vec, as.list(adf[1,]))
#> $avec
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]$b
#> [1] "a"
```

Other things I’ve tried.

```r
purrr::flatten(toomany) # breaks up avec again
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "b"
c(avec = vec, as.list(adf[1,]), recursive = TRUE)
#> avec1 avec2     a     b 
#>   "1"   "2"   "1"   "a"
list(avec = vec, as.vector(adf[1,]))
#> $avec
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
list(vec, unlist(adf[1,]))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   a   b 
#> "1" "a"
```

I didn’t think this would be so hard! Do I have to assemble the list in
text and parse it? I’m missing something. Created on 2019-03-01 by the
[reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Does this help: `vec <- 1:2 ; broken <- c(avec = list(vec), as.list(tbl[2,])); do.call(testit, broken)` for your actual problem?

Comment: No -- it still breaks avec into pieces

Comment: That's strange as it gives `4` here which is what you were looking for.

Comment: ah! list(vec) is not the same as as.list(vec) ... didn't read closely enough.

Comment: Yes, that works in the actual application too, thank you!

Comment: From what I see, another option for you could be `vec <- 1:20; works <- c(avec = list(vec), as.list(iris[2,])); sum(lengths(works))` This works for any number of columns and any length of `vec`